# HTML displays php code after Submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hey guys i have a simple html form, that will `POST` the username and pass to a php file which will then check it with some predefined values, but whenever i click submit it opens a page with the php code for some reason, i can't figure out why!

**HTML code:**

```
<form name="userForm" action="login.php" method="post">
<h3 >Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /></h3>
<h3>Password: <input type="password" name="pass"/></h3>
<button name="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $uname = $_POST['uname'];
   $pass = $_POST['pass'];
}
if($uname == "admin" && $pass =="notell" {
   echo 'finally';
} else {
   echo 'plz work man';
})
```

any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: I don't recommend you use this method for a login system, also where do you close the `php`... **?>**

Comment: check your file extension it must be **.php** Also check your server support php

Comment: You are working on server ?

Comment: PHP is not executing on server side. You need to add php execution code on server. What's your operating system and server?

Answer (score 0):

Your question clearly points to the problem that either your PHP file isn't in a webroot directory or your server(whichever server you are using) is not configured to execute PHP code. In that case Form submission will work because it's browsers job to submit form but any PHP code is not being parsed and it is showing you plain PHP code.

In case of apache your php files should be in htdocs directory by default which is /var/www/

In case of nginx it will be usr/local/nginx/html by default.

Answer (score 0):

> Try to close your code properly. In **if($uname == "admin" && $pass =="notell"** close the small bracket before starting the curly bracket not after the else ending.
>
> **if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {** close this curly bracket at the end of the code not before the line **if($uname == "admin" && $pass =="notell"**

I have re-written the your php code below.

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $uname = $_POST['uname'];
   $pass = $_POST['pass'];

  if($uname == "admin" && $pass =="notell") {
   echo 'finally';
  } else {
      echo 'plz work man';
   }
 }
?>
```

I don't recommend this method. Your code is widely open for [SQL-injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use the [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).